# How to setup a self destructing file system?

Tags: security, filesystems, privacy

How can one setup a file system (i.e. a folder or a partition) with confidential information in such a way that it can be easily destroyed (i.e. overwritten with random data on the hard-drive) when asked by a third party to login in the computer?

Imagine that you are editing the next documentary about the next whistle blower on your (air-tight) laptop, but are requested by the authorities to login in your laptop (e.g. when crossing a border). Is there a way to set-up your laptop so that you can discreetly remove the data from a specific folder or partition while showing around another part of your file-system?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask states "What types of questions should I avoid asking? First, make sure that your question is on-topic for this site... You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. "

Comment: @k7aay this question actually matches the criteria you laid out.

Comment: The simplest solution is a RAM drive (may be additionally encrypted to make cold boot attacks more complicated). If the computer reboots or crashes the stored data are gone, hence it is destroyed.

Comment: @Robert That certainly solved the problem for someone writing an article, but I doubt you can hold all the files required for editing a video documentary in RAM, and if it is cached on the hard drive, it somehow defeat the purpose? (Or am I missing a point?)

Comment: @Jeremy Right. However when it comes to an IT border control I would not want to have any problematic data on my device, independently if it is encrypted and/or hidden or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort of. What you want fairly closely (but not exactly) matches the [Veracrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeraCrypt) and [Truecrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueCrypt) plausible deniability feature, which was designed for just this purpose.  This feature allows you to have 2 passwords. One of them us where you save your work, and the other you use if forced to decrypt your computer.  There is no known way for the other party to know you have 2 passwords, or that you are using this feature

Writing a large file while logged into the "dummy / innocent" account risks overwriting your real valuable data, because, of course, it needs to work with the whole available disk so as not to give up that it's being used for plausible deniability.

Comment: I would not recommend to rely on the plausible deniability feature. Border control staff is not that stupid as it is a well known feature. Even more: Using Veracrypt at all can be a problem if you don't use plausible deniability feature and the border staff tries to force you to present the password for the hidden data...

Comment: @robert your evidence for this please? In what way is it detectable or broken - assuming plausible data? Are you aware of cases this has caused the Veracrypt user issues?

Comment: There are several indicators: 1. You have the software installed. 2. there are files that are most likely Veracrypt containers (see [here](https://www.raedts.biz/forensics/detecting-truecrypt-veracrypt-volumes/)). The person at the border can act very simple: if one indicator is true they force you to deliver the password for the image and the hidden image inside. Technically everything is still fine, it is more a social problem.

Comment: Again @Robert - are you aware of border security doing anything when they see Veracrypt to compromise plausible deniability. From a legal POV I can't see how you could be forced to provide something you may not gave, and indeed most people do not use this function because of risk of data loss. I put to you that short of the gold standard of not travelling with useful data on the laptop, this is the best you have - and 99.9% of the time its good enough. The rest of the time you are stuffed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution consists in

1. creating two accounts with reasonable names (e.g. one being your first name, one being the first letter of your first name concatenated with your last name),
2. setting both of them with the same public files and folders (so that login in one is looking like loging in the other one), but
3. setting one with access to a private folder, and the other account to discreetly delete (i.e. encrypt it with a random key, so that to overwrite the corresponding space on the hard drive with unintelligible data) such private folder.

Comment: I'm pleased you have a solution to your problem - but you should provide more detailed information (ie how to access private folder and discreetly delete).   Your solution is arguably inferior to mine because its not easy to discretely wipe a filesystem (performance will suffer and disk IO will be visible, processess will run, plausible will likely be lost, and this process is slow.   Also, if is not at all helpful if the attacker takes the first typical step - do a bitcopy dump of the raw data)

Comment: @davidgo I asked the question on stackexchange because I was not happy with my solution, but stated anyway as an example of solution to improve upon.

Comment: Ok. Not seen that before here!